# [ng-bootstrap]: Passing function to a modal threw a service

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm have create a service which call my different modal. So I have a modal call "Confirm Modal" which can take 3 parameters, a confirm function, a refuse function and a body. Here is the following modal:

```
export class ConfirmModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() acceptFunc;
  @Output() refuseFunc?;
  @Input() body: string;
  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  async confirmModal() {
    await this.acceptFunc;
    this.closeModal();
  }

  async refuseModal() {
    if (this.refuseFunc) await this.refuseFunc();
    this.closeModal();
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.activeModal.close('Modal Closed');
  }
}
```

In my modal service I create the following function to open this modal

```
openConfirmModal(accept: <P = any>(props?: P) => void, body: string,         refuse?: <P = any>(props?: P) => void): NgbModalRef {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmModalComponent, { size: 'lg' });
  modalRef.componentInstance.accept = accept;
  if (refuse) modalRef.componentInstance.refuse = refuse;
  modalRef.componentInstance.body = body;
  return modalRef;
}
```

`

I'm calling this function as follow:

```
openConfirmModal() {
  this.modalService.openConfirmModal(this.myFunc.bind(this), 'Test')
}

myFunc() {
  console.log('Work !');
}
```

The problem is my function myFunc is never call, so how can I pass a function from a component to my modal through a service ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If yes please add that too.

Comment: @AmitChigadani no, I don't have any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your ConfirmModalComponent, you're not invoking the method with parenthesis, change

```
async confirmModal() {
  await this.acceptFunc;
  this.closeModal();
}
```

to

```
async confirmModal() {
  await this.acceptFunc();
  this.closeModal();
}
```

And on your openConfirmModal method, you're defining the functions with names different from the ones you're using on the component, change these two lines

```
modalRef.componentInstance.accept = accept;
if (refuse) modalRef.componentInstance.refuse = refuse;
```

to

```
modalRef.componentInstance.acceptFunc = accept;
if (refuse) modalRef.componentInstance.refuseFunc = refuse;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a method in the component related to modal , just call it like this
this.modalRef.content.yourfunction();